# Can I use kotlin.reflect to get a value of a field

Tags: reflection, kotlin

```
class A{
     private var p:MyObj? = null
}
```

It seems that I can't get p by **A::p**,
Or I can only get it by java?

My kotlin version is

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-2'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get it because you do it outside of that class when the property is `private`. You have a few options here:

1. create a function returning `this::p` (`fun func(): KProperty0<MyObj?> = this::p`)
2. make that property `public`
3. use reflection. *This is probably the slowest, least performant and very tightly coupled option. Use it only if you can't use the others.* You can use Kotlin's reflection like so: `A::class.memberProperties.find { it.name == "p" } as KProperty1<A, MyObj?>`

Comment: I just want to use reflect in unit test only. That's  why my problem contains reflect.And will you add **apply{ isAccessible = true}** and  **compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
**, so that I'll accept your answer to help someone else.